# Page closing and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics

I have a web application requirement when I'm to log some data using the event tracking feature of the google analytics. I'm using the onbeforeunload method using a method like so:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = fnUnloadHandler
        function fnUnloadHandler() {
        endTime = new Date()
        var dif = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()
        var diffSeconds = dif / 1000
        var timeSpent = Math.floor(diffSeconds)

        //Register time on app\n");
        RegisterMultipleDataOnGA('timeonapp', timeSpent)

       return 'page closing'
    }
```

The Register multiple on GA method takes care of logging the data sing the _gaq.push method of google analytics. It just seems that this works a little inconsistently in web browsers, and it does not work at all in the mobile browsers.

In web browsers if I have something like a fiddler running I notice that the service call to Google Analytics is made, but it shows as pending status, and the page then closed. I'm not sure if this service call is completed for the data to be logged into Analytics, and so:

1. Will onbeforeunload work perfectly in mobile browsers too?
2. Is there a way I can ensure that data is logged into analytics before the page closes?

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`beforeunload` is very tricky and behaves differently across browsers, so I used a modal window to track or wait until my request is completed but to my disappointment that doesn't work in Chrome.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561345/onbeforeunload-seamless-behavior-in-all-browsers) thread for more.

Comment: For the purpose of getting time on page, I'm now trying to us _trackTiming method to use. Wonder if I'll be able to track each user visit any differently. Will let you know the results of it soon.

Comment: cool, i believe GA gives you average time spent on each page too, check that out. also a vote up would help

Comment: Not able to track the time on app using _trackTiming it seems that many developers are facing the same issue. It seems like this method is still work in progress.